# Integrating Symfony Routing and Twig using Symfony Twig Bridge

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml, twig-extension

I use in my code Twig and Symfony routing which I would like to integrate with Twig using Symfony Twig Bridge.

I have them both installed and what I need to do is to add to Twig extensions Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension which requires Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator.

UrlGenerator requires 2 arguments:

- routes collection
- request context

So in my yaml services file I have:

```
    router:
    class: Symfony\Component\Routing\Router
    arguments:
        - '@yaml.file.loader'
        - '%routing.file%'
        - { 'cache_dir' : '%cache.dir%' }
        - '@request.context'
```

---

```
    twig:
    class: Twig_Environment
    calls:
        - ['addExtension', ['@twig.extensions.debug']]
        - ['addExtension', ['@twig.extensions.translate']]
        - ['addExtension', ['@twig.extensions.routing']]
    arguments:
        - '@twig.loader'
        - '%twig.options%'
```

---

```
    twig.extensions.routing:
    class: Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension
    public: false
    arguments:
        - '@twig.url.generator'
```

And finally UrlGenerator:

```
    twig.url.generator:
    class: Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator
    public: false
    arguments:
        - '@router'
        - '@request.context'
```

Unfortunatelly @router is not route collection type. It has method getRouteCollection which allows to get data required by UrlGenerator and it works if I add extension manually eg. from controller. But I don't want to split services definition between different files and prefer to keep them in yaml services definition.

**So the question is**: how to pass as an argument to UrlGenerator not the raw object Router but result of getRouteCollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

### Using Symfony expression language

If you have Symfony Expression Language component installed, you can do this in your service definition:

```
twig.url.generator:
    class: Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator
    public: false
    arguments:
        - "@=service('router').getRouteCollection()"
        - "@request.context"
```

### Using factory

If for some reason you don't want to use Symfony Expression Language, you can do it using a factory class which is responsible for instantiating your url generator.

```
class UrlGeneratorFactory
{
    private $router;

    private $requestContext;

    public function __construct($router, $requestContext)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->requestContext = $requestContext;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return new UrlGenerator($this->router->getRouteCollection(), $this->requestContext);
    }
}
```

And in your *yaml* set url generator definition to:

```
twig.url.generator.factory:
    class: UrlGeneratorFactory
    arguments: ["@router", "@request.context"]

twig.url.generator:
    class:   Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator
    factory: ["@twig.url.generator.factory", create]
```